# VS Code [angular] karma test debug breakpoints only work once or twice without restarting VS code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, jasmine, karma-runner, test-explorer

I have been using VS code to debug my Angular jasmine karma tests for a while but I have always had a problem whereby after debugging a test several times the breakpoints stop working. I have to restart VS code to make them work again and it seems to be getting worse i.e. stops working after a single debug!

FYI, debugging works fine until it stops. After the breakpoints stop working they are still shown as attached (i.e. coloured in red) and the tests run correctly.

I have Karma Test Explorer (for Angular, Jasmine and Mocha) installed:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucono.karma-test-explorer

I have 'Test Explorer: Use Native Testing' enabled (but the issue happens without native testing too).

I do not use the launch.json to attach.

n.b. I often get a notification/error saying a test operation is still in progress/active when it gets into this state and restarting is the only way I know how to reset this!

My karma file is configure as like this:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "@angular-devkit/build-angular"],
    plugins: [
      require("karma-coverage"),
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-jasmine-html-reporter"),
      require("karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter"),
      require("@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma"),
      require("karma-spec-reporter"),
      require("karma-junit-reporter"),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require("path").join(__dirname, "./coverage"),
      reports: ["html", "lcovonly", "text-summary", "cobertura"],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    // reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage ? ['dots', 'coverage-istanbul'] : ['dots', 'kjhtml'],
    reporters:
      config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ["dots", "coverage-istanbul", "junit"]
        : ["dots", "kjhtml", "junit"],
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5, // limit number of lines logged per test
      suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary
      suppressFailed: false, // do not print information about failed tests
      suppressPassed: false, // do not print information about passed tests
      suppressSkipped: true, // do not print information about skipped tests
      showSpecTiming: false, // print the time elapsed for each spec
    },
    mime: {
      "text/x-typescript": ["ts", "tsx"],
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
    autoWatch: true,
    singleRun: false,
    files: [
      {
        pattern: "src/assets/**/*.png",
        watched: true,
        included: true,
        served: true,
        nocache: false,
      },
    ],
    proxies: {
      "/assets/": "/base/src/assets/images/fixtures",
    },
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox"],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: "ChromeHeadless",
        flags: [
          "--no-sandbox",
          "--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-test-profile",
          "--disable-web-security",
          "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0",
          "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
        ],
        debug: true,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if other VS Code extensions are interfering. Disable them and test if the problem remains. If that doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall the Karma Test Explorer extension if it's a configuration issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it. I've also tried fully reinstalling VS code.

Comment: @BenThomson Double check your Karma configuration file - specifically the autoWatch and singleRun options. 
Make sure autoWatch is true to rerun tests on file changes, and singleRun is false to keep the Karma server running.
Try restarting the Karma server by stopping it with "ng test --watch=false" and starting it again with "ng test". Sometimes the server gets in a bad state.

Check VS Code settings related to debugging like debug.internalConsoleOptions and debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere. The latter lets you set breakpoints anywhere if true.

Comment: I've tried both of those options. Looking on GitHub I think this issue is specific to WSL2 and is unlikely to be solved now with Karma being discontinued so I think the best option is for us to migrate to Jest.

Comment: Also the extension isn't started by ng test as it runs on its own without the need for running things manually.